# How to calculate the total seconds from now plus n days

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to send a notification on every Tuesday at 12:00pm

I want to get an exact time in the future in seconds until Tuesday at 12:00pm

```
import datetime
from datetime import date , timedelta

today = datetime.date.today()
Tuesday = datetime.timedelta( (1-today.weekday()) % 7 ) + timedelta(hours=12)
seconds_to_call = Tuesday.total_seconds() 

print(seconds_to_call)

# Gives exactly 5 days in seconds 432,000 + timedelta(hours=12) 43200
```

**# Gives exactly 5 days in seconds 432,000 + timedelta(hours=12) 43200**

How can I get Tuesday 00:00 plus the 12 hours timedelta(hours=12) 43200

So then I would have Tuesday 12pm

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# get the date and time for now
now = datetime.now()

# get the current day at midnight
today = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

# get Tuesday at midnight
tues = today + timedelta( (1-today.weekday()) % 7 )

# get the seconds from now until Tuesday at midnight
seconds_to_tues_midnight = (tues - now).total_seconds()

# get the seconds from now until Tuesday at noon
seconds_to_tues_noon = seconds_to_tues_midnight + timedelta(hours=12)/timedelta(seconds=1)
```

### As a Function

```py
from typing import Tuple

def time_to_tuesday(now: datetime) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    today = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    tues = today + timedelta( (1-today.weekday()) % 7 )
    midnight = (tues - now).total_seconds()
    noon = midnight + timedelta(hours=12)/timedelta(seconds=1)
    
    return midnight, noon


time_to_tuesday(datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

### First question

> I want to get an exact time in the future in seconds until Tuesday at 12:00pm

I suppose you want the exact time in seconds untile Tuesday 12:00 from today

```
import datetime

def relative_date(reference, weekday, timevalue):
    hour, minute = divmod(timevalue, 1)
    minute *= 60
    days = reference.weekday()+(reference.weekday() - weekday)
    return (reference + datetime.timedelta(days=days)).replace(hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=0, microsecond=0)

today = datetime.datetime.now()
Tuesday = relative_date(today, 1, 12)

seconds_to_call = (Tuesday - today).total_seconds()

print(seconds_to_call)

# OUTPUT: 405778.097769
```

You have to calculate the difference between two dates, today and the next Tuesday. The function `relative_date` calculate the exact date of the next Tuesday and set the hour to `12:00:00.000`.

### Second question

> I want to run the program get the number of seconds until 00:00 then had the number of seconds until 12 (43,200)

You can do it like this:

```
import datetime

def relative_date(reference, weekday, timevalue):
    hour, minute = divmod(timevalue, 1)
    minute *= 60
    days = reference.weekday()+(reference.weekday() - weekday)
    return (reference + datetime.timedelta(days=days)).replace(hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=0, microsecond=0)

today = datetime.datetime.now()
Tuesday_midnight = relative_date(today, 1, 0)

seconds_to_call = ((Tuesday_midnight - today) + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)).total_seconds()

print(seconds_to_call)

# OUTPUT: 405778.097769
```

In this case is useless to calculate the time until midnight, you can get the total_seconds, as in the code for the first question, directly from noon.

Comment: Thank you that got the output in seconds, I was expecting a smaller method of doing so, and your function worked perfect.